# Is it safe to call ko.applyBindings without any parameters?

Tags: knockout.js

This is the only official doc I could find on ko.applyBindings():

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

It's not a real formal written document that says exactly what is optional/etc.  In testing it appears that calling ko.applyBindings() allows for bindings on a global scope, and it appears to work fine.  Has anyone that studied the source code (or know more about KO than I do), know if this is safe or not?  Any performance issues?

This is the start of my "app" object for an SPA I'm working on:

```
var app = {

self: this,
datacontext: new DataContext(),
dataservice: new DataService(),
viewModels: {
    main: new MainViewModel(),
    folderDetails: new FolderDetailsViewModel()
},

init: function() {

    ko.applyBindings();

    Sammy(function() {

        this.get('#:folder', function() {
            self.doFolderRoute(this.params.folder);
        });

        // Override this function so that Sammy doesn't mess with forms
        this._checkFormSubmission = function(form) {
            return (false);
        };

    }).run();

},

doFolderRoute: function(id) {
    console.log("doFolderRoute: " + id);
}
}
```

I could do ko.applyBindings(self.viewModels), to restrict data-bind to the models... but I kind of like the freedom of being able to bind to anything and don't mind (even like) typing out app.viewModels.main in my code, vs just "main".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `ko.applyBindings()`, Knockout won't know about your view model. `$root` won't be set and neither will `$data` at the root level. Obviously, you can simply not reference those variables. Also the event bindings pass `$data` to the event handler function, which in this case will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it could break things.. if not now, in future releases at least.  I just noticed I can still reference global items like "app" even if I pass in a view model, so I'll go ahead and pass a model so I can at least be "normal".  Also saves some typing if I don't want to use app.viewModels. everywhere.

Comment: There is a valid use case for `applyBindings` with no model - when you have components on a page that operate without a model, you still need to call it. I just call `ko.applyBindings( {} );` which does the trick.

Comment: Another possibly valid case ko.applyBindings(data), also with no model for a similar simple structure as @Quango above. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KcghG/ (from @rneimeyer)

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI - This is my updated app (still work in progress obviously):

I figured out self: this I had in the original code was pointing to window, so obviously that was a bad idea and one reason I was getting weird results when I tried ko.applyBindings(self.viewModels).

```
var app = {

datacontext: new DataContext(),
dataservice: new DataService(),
viewModels: {
    main: new MainViewModel(),
    folderDetails: new FolderDetailsViewModel()
},

init: function() {

    ko.applyBindings(app.viewModels);

    Sammy(function() {

        this.get('#:folder', function() {
            self.doFolderRoute(this.params.folder);
        });

        // Override this function so that Sammy doesn't mess with forms
        this._checkFormSubmission = function(form) {
            return (false);
        };

    }).run();

    widgetLib.init();

},

doFolderRoute: function(id) {
    console.log("doFolderRoute: " + id);
}
}
```