# KnockoutJS: What Does Calling applyBindings Without Arguments do?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, magento2

I'm working through some -- interesting -- code that I didn't write, and came across a RequireJS module that seems to initialize a KnockoutJS instance for the application.

```
define([
    'ko',
    './template/engine',
    'knockoutjs/knockout-repeat',
    'knockoutjs/knockout-fast-foreach',
    'knockoutjs/knockout-es5',
    './bind/scope',
    './bind/staticChecked',
    './bind/datepicker',
    './bind/outer_click',
    './bind/keyboard',
    './bind/optgroup',
    './bind/fadeVisible',
    './bind/mage-init',
    './bind/after-render',
    './bind/i18n',
    './bind/collapsible',
    './bind/autoselect',
    './extender/observable_array',
    './extender/bound-nodes'
], function (ko, templateEngine) {
    'use strict';

    ko.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

This code calls `ko.applyBindings()` **without** a view model.  I'm very new to knockout, but **all** the tutorials I've seen indicate you need to pass `applyBindings` a viewModel object.

What does calling `applyBindings` without parameters do, exactly?

My end goal here is to figure out how this application (Magento 2, if anyone's curious) is using Knockout to render things, so I'm looking for reasons a Knockout developer might do something like this.

Comment: It looks like it's fine, just $root and $data won't get set.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903650/is-it-safe-to-call-ko-applybindings-without-any-parameters

Comment: @skalpin I'm afraid I don't know what that means.  Its my understanding you NEED a view model for anything to happen on the page with Knockout.  Is that not correct?

Comment: yup @AlanStorm as ko is  mv`VM` - you need a viewModel ,if you are looking for `2-way` binding (i hope you know) . applyBinding does the job of activating ko if you pass viewModel as first Parameter well and good its binds view with viewModel and maintains the changes in view & vm intact . sample to play around http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/30363/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via some comments here and additional research, I was able to come up with the answer I was looking for.

My mistake was thinking `ko.applyBindings()` main job was to associate a view model (javascript object) with the view (HTML page).  While that's **one** of `applyBindings`' jobs, `applyBindings` **also** starts rendering the view (HTML page).  In Knockout's world, rendering the view means (at least?) scanning the HTML page for `data-bind` attributes, and processing those attributes.

By itself, processing the `data-bind` attributes with no data would be pretty useful.  However, if the application you're using has created **custom bindings** (as seen in [this tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=custombindings)), there's no limit to calling what `applyBindings` can do.  In my specific case, Magento 2 has a custom binding named `scope` that (via some other mechanisms) will bind data for a specific node context.

Answer (score 1):

Most of knockout's functionality won't make sense without a viewmodel, but that doesn't make it required. You can see in [the source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/241c26ca82e6e4b3eaee39e3dc0a92f85bc1df0c/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js) that nothing breaks when you don't pass a viewmodel parameter: it just sets the binding context as `undefined`:

```
function getBindingContext(viewModelOrBindingContext) {
    return viewModelOrBindingContext && (viewModelOrBindingContext instanceof ko.bindingContext)
        ? viewModelOrBindingContext
        : new ko.bindingContext(viewModelOrBindingContext);
}
```

A few examples I can think of why one would `applyBindings` without a viewmodel:

- Injecting static templates
- Attaching event listener methods that are in the global context

I must admit though that these feel a bit contrived... I actually don't know why the code you've shown does it...

```js
window.logClick = function(data, event) {
  console.log("Click");
};

ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div data-bind="template: 'header-template'"></div>

  <button data-bind="click: logClick">click listener in window</button>
</div>



<script id="header-template" type="text/html">

  <h1>A header inserted by template</h2>
  
</script>
```